# Excel: Count the number of Unique Values within a Specific Criteria

Tags: excel, function, count

**Objective:** 
Determine the Average Number of Users logging in per Month, based on data from the audit history.

**Metadata Format**
Tab-delimited Spreadsheet with approximately 600,000 entries per month.
Column A shows the User ID (ie. E12345).
Column B shows the Event Date (ie 30/01/2015).

**Example:**
E12345 30/01/2015
E12345 30/01/2015
E67890 30/01/2015
E67890 01/02/2015

I need a function that counts the unique number of entries per day from Column A, based on the date (Column B). From there I can average the totals. Not sure if it would be better to run a macro to separate the data into sheets based on date (Column B), or simply write a function within the one sheet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This gives total number of unique entries over a designated range (rows 1:10 in the below formula):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A10&B1:B10<>"", MATCH(A1:A10&"@"&B1:B10,A1:A10&"@"&B1:B10,0)),ROW(A1:A10)-ROW(A1)+1)>0,1))
```

Note: you must confirm this formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.